# 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access when adding role | discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to ass different roles to people rapidly to give users the impression of their name being rainbow ( yes I know its against TOS ), and I am starting by adding roles to people before I remove them. However, when adding roles I get the error in the title of this post. I have looked into this and tried quite a few ways to fix it. The bot has a higher role than the roles being give out. Here is my code and the output:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
role_name = "Rainbow Six Seige"
peopleWithRole = []
guild = discord.Guild 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    guild = bot.guilds[0]
    colours = [discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='red'),
               discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='green'),
               discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='blue')
               ]

    role = discord.utils.find(
        lambda r: r.name == role_name, guild.roles)
        
    for user in guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            peopleWithRole.append(user)

    for color in colours:
        for user in peopleWithRole:
            await user.add_roles(color)

bot.run("my token")
```

output:

```
Logged in as
test bot
------
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\test.py", line 29, in on_ready
    await user.add_roles(color)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have a role given to the bot which has access to `managing roles`. Also when you add the bot from the dev portal you can give it permissions needed.

<s>Best practice for verified bots is to make a role called `BOT` with all the permissions and give it to all the bots you have in the server</s>

Comment: This is not best practice, you should only give the permissions that a bot needs to perform its responsibilities, and the best way to do that is to manage permissions per bot

Comment: The "best practice" commonly used that Abdulaziz may refer to is solely a role to group together bots so they show together in the side bar. Ideally, you want permissions to be handled on a case by case basis to restrict access to the necessary as goes for users too.

Comment: Not only this never was a best practice, it contravenes modern information security practices, like zero trust and least privilege, and is actually quite dangerous in case any of the bots misbehaves or gets hacked

Comment: You are right, I meant for verified bots only. I have no idea how did i mess that. anyway it is not deleted. Thanks for the feedback <3

Answer (score 9):

I'm just leaving this for any others struggling with this b/c I spent 3 days trying to debug a 50001 error and found nothing and this thread comes up as one of the first on google.

Apparently, if the Discord server your Bot / integration mandates multi-factor authentication, the developer account associated with your Bot MUST have MFA enabled. I enabled it on my discord developer account, and the 50001 errors immediately resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Please check twice that your parameters are correct:

1. Discord Bot Token,
2. Discord Guild ID,
3. Discord Role ID / name,
4. Discord User ID.

In my case, I was using a token from a different bot on the same server. After changing the token to the correct token, everything worked.

**Morale of the story is**: always check the dumbest and simplest things first!

Comment: An easy way to find out that you are using the wrong token is to look at the members panel to the right on your Discord server: if the bot appears offline, then you might be experiencing the same problem as me.