# Discord.py slash commands are giving 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot using python, and I have run into a problem while adding slash commands.

Whenever I run the bot, after a few seconds I get an error. The only information on this error I could find was [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307903/403-forbidden-error-code-50001-missing-access-when-adding-role-discord-py), but none of the responses fixed the issue.

Any/all help is much appreciated, thanks!

Main Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = intents)

class myClient(discord.Client):
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f"Bot is now online.")

    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        await bot.process_commands(message)

    @bot.slash_command(
        description="Test.",
        guild_ids=[redacted])
    async def test(self, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
        await ctx.respond("Test")

client = myClient()

bot.run(redacted)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Ignoring exception in on_connect
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 382, in _run_event
        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1025, in on_connect
        await self.sync_commands()
      File "C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 558, in sync_commands
        registered_guild_commands[guild_id] = await self.register_commands(
      File "C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 471, in register_commands
        registered = await register("bulk", data)
      File "C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 351, in request
        raise Forbidden(response, data)
    discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

I have given the bot all of the permissions that it needs:

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Here's what I did to fix this:

Before doing anything below, make sure you selected the correct **guild_id** in the slash_command decorator. If this doesn't work, try this:

1. Kick the bot from the server it is currently in.
2. Go to: https://discord.com/developers/applications/, head to your preferred bot, then to "0Auth2" and finally to "Url Generator".
3. Under scopes select "bot" **AND** *"applications.commands"*, then under bot permissions, you can select all the permissions for your bot.
4. Let the bot rejoin the right server and start your Bot, now it shouldn't give you an error message anymore.

[Reference](https://github.com/Tomato6966/Discord-js-handler-slash-Commands/issues/1) (i know it is Discord.js, but it's a similar issue)

This fixed my error message, hope it helps.